# R Shiny: Infinite Recursion

Tags: r, recursion, shiny

I'm working on a Shiny app that seeks to guess the next word in a user-entered text snippet.  To do this, I am loading three dataframes that contain possible guesses to this next word and using grepl to find tri- or bi-gram matches to the end of the user-entered text. I built this without error or issue in a "regular" R, but when converting it to Shiny, I'm getting this error:

**Error : evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?**

As other Stack Overflow posts have suggested, I fiddled with the options(expressions = ) value, but am still experiencing the error. Without much other information to guide me, and noting that it has worked without issue, can anyone see where I've gone wrong?  Thanks in advance!

For background, I'm running: Win 7, 64-bit OS | R v3.1.1 | RStudio v0.98.944

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Capstone: Word Guesser"),
      fluidRow(
         column(12, 
            mainPanel(
               h4('Sentence Fragment'),
               p('Please enter a snippet of text - with this as a start, the app will provide you 5 guesses in ranked order to complete your phrase'),
               textInput('sentence', "Snippet:", value = "Enter some text and have a great"),
               h4('Guesses'),
               p('Below are our top five guesses for the word that completes this snippet'),
               verbatimTextOutput("final.guesses")
            )
         )
      )
))
```

server.R

```
options(expressions = 10000)
quad.grams <- readRDS("quadgrams.rds")
tri.grams <- readRDS("trigrams.rds")
kneser.ney <- readRDS("kneserney.rds")
library(shiny)
library(tm)
library(plyr)
library(stringi)
library(RWeka)
library(stringr)
function(input, output, clientData, session) {
   observe({
      sentence <- reactive({as.character(input$sentence)})
      sentence <- reactive({str_replace_all(sentence(), "[[:punct:]]", "")})
      sentence <- reactive({tolower(sentence())})
      sentence <- reactive({scan_tokenizer(sentence())})
      n <- reactive({length(sentence())})
      tri.frag <- reactive({paste(sentence()[n() - 2], sentence()[n() - 1], sentence()[n()])})
      bi.frag <- reactive({paste(sentence()[n() - 1], sentence()[n()])})
      quad.guesses <- reactive({quad.grams[grepl(tri.frag(), quad.grams$n1.Gram) == TRUE, 2]})
      tri.guesses <- reactive({tri.grams[grepl(bi.frag(), tri.grams$n1.Gram) == TRUE, 2]})
      guesses <- reactive({c(quad.guesses(), tri.guesses(), kneser.ney$nGram)})
      output$final.guesses <- renderPrint({guesses()[1:5]})
   })
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is here (can't test to be sure):

```
observe({
  sentence <- reactive({as.character(input$sentence)})
  sentence <- reactive({str_replace_all(sentence(), "[[:punct:]]", "")})
  sentence <- reactive({tolower(sentence())})
  sentence <- reactive({scan_tokenizer(sentence())})
```

These four lines are all making `sentence` reactive, and each line depends on itself, `input$sentence` and each of the other lines causing shiny to be confused as to how things work.  A better solution would be:

```
observe({
  sentence1 <- reactive({as.character(input$sentence)})
  sentence2 <- reactive({str_replace_all(sentence1(), "[[:punct:]]", "")})
  sentence3 <- reactive({tolower(sentence2())})
  sentence4 <- reactive({scan_tokenizer(sentence3())})
```

You may be able to remove the `sentence1` line - I think `input$sentence` is already character. The remaining lines could be combined if you like such as:

```
  sentence <- reactive({scan_tokenizer( tolower(
                str_replace_all(input$sentence, "[[:punct:]]", "") ))
             })
```

Comment: thanks again for addressing my shiny question - you had helped me out a few months ago, and I greatly appreciate it. I kept fiddling with it and came to the same conclusion this morning. I will, however, take your advice and simplify the processing steps.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of causing another infinite loop, I'm happy to say I can post my own answer. The issue seemed to be the re-use of the 'sentence' variable. I guess when using a reactive, you can't re-use variables over and over even though you may just be transforming them.  Anyway, this code now works:

server.R

```
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 50*1024^2)
options(expressions = 10000)
quad.grams <- readRDS("quadgrams.rds")
tri.grams <- readRDS("trigrams.rds")
kneser.ney <- readRDS("kneserney.rds")
library(shiny)
library(tm)
library(plyr)
library(stringi)
library(RWeka)
library(stringr)
function(input, output, clientData, session) {
      snippet <- reactive({as.character(input$sentence)})
      clean.snippet <- reactive({str_replace_all(snippet(), "[[:punct:]]", "")})
      lower.snippet <- reactive({tolower(clean.snippet())})
      tokens <- reactive({scan_tokenizer(lower.snippet())})
      n <- reactive({length(tokens())})
      tri.frag <- reactive({paste(tokens()[n() - 2], tokens()[n() - 1], tokens()[n()])})
      bi.frag <- reactive({paste(tokens()[n() - 1], tokens()[n()])})
      quad.guesses <- reactive({quad.grams[grepl(tri.frag(), quad.grams$n1.Gram) == TRUE, 2]})
      tri.guesses <- reactive({tri.grams[grepl(bi.frag(), tri.grams$n1.Gram) == TRUE, 2]})
      guesses <- reactive({c(quad.guesses(), tri.guesses(), kneser.ney$nGram)})
      output$final.guesses <- renderPrint({guesses()[1:5]})
}
```